# Can a graph exhibit both Preferential Attachment and Small-World properties at the same time?

Tags: graph-theory

I am analyzing a graph of protein-protein interactions. The data has been sourced from the [STRING website](https://string-db.org/cgi/download.pl).

The original directed multigraph has been converted as follows: select largest strongly connected component subgraph, then convert to an undirected graph.

```
Number of nodes: 3756
Number of edges: 56584
Average degree:  30.1299
```

During further analysis I observe that:

- The graph appears to exhibit the properties of a small-world graph, namely the graph's average shortest path is small (`3.12`) and its clustering coefficient is relatively high (`0.46`). This, I believe, is also referred to as the `Preferential Attachment Model`.
- The graph's degree distribution exhibits small world properties i.e. most nodes have small degree and some nodes have very high degree.

[image]

Now, I am not a great expert in graph theory and mathematics, but I am curious to find out if the above findings are in any way contradictory, indicating a problem with the underlying graph, or whether this is indeed something that can be observed in real-world networks.

Comment: You can't "observe the preferential attachment model" in a real life network; the preferential attachment model is a specific method for generating a random graph with certain features.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. That is true. But I am also thinking that the fact that NetworkX has a metric named `preferential_attachment()` does suggest that it is possible to asses a real-life network for the properties of that particular model.